# manage the color of a TextView in a GridView

Tags: android

I need to know how can I change the color of a single TextView in a GridView when I click it.
Different TextViews need different colors.

I tried to change color with the id with the function setonIitemListener, but it doesn't work

Comment: Voting to close as way to broad with absolutely no effort shown. Here is a starting point. `public void onClick(View v){ v.setColor(Color.RED); }`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include some code showing what you tried and try to give more details regarding what you want to accomplish and what problem you are facing with your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up  `OnItemClickListener` which correspond to the item position.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long arg3)
    {
        //Selected item is at index "position"
        //now you can get arg 
        TextView tv = v.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
        tv.setColor(ContextCompact.getColor(mContext, R.color.reddish);
    }
});
```